# How to kill the Monkey Wizard?

Tags: candy-box-2

How can I kill him? He jumps when I approach and I get stuck at the end of the "map", sometimes I am able to teleport to the beginning but he jumps again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you have beaten the octopus king, enchant his crown with jaspers. Then all you need to do is sit in the corner, casting the occasional erase spell and the crown will kill him for you.

Comment: I just threw acid rain whenever it recharged and erased every time too many magic balls built up (I hadn't beaten octopus king before then) I used pink gloves and then just magic

Answer (score 0):

You must have this

- light armor (trade for 15,000 candies with the forge)
- Defeat the octopus King (must have pink clove enchanted)
- once you killed it must enchant crown (wishing well come in handy)
- obstatin and Jaspers enchant your choice I suggest obstatin enchant

Comment: I edited this a bit to try and make it more readable.

Answer (score -1):

Actually the obsidian enchant is better. I tried it and killed the monkey without losing any hp (I also had the boots of introspection).