# How do you obtain the octopus king's crown?

Tags: candy-box-2

I've heard that the octopus king will drop his crown upon dying, but I've killed him many times and I see no crown.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade.  If you have multiple questions, feel free to post them separately.  As for the monkey wizard, [that seems to have been asked already](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/137144/42984)

Comment: I've removed the second question.  [It has already been asked](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/137144/how-to-kill-the-monkey-wizard)

Answer (score 2):

He drops it on death.  Check your inventory, under "Hat" in the top right portion of where gear is listed, you should have a drop down.  If you see a drop down, you should be able to select the crown from it.

The [Candy Box 2 wiki](http://candybox2.net/wiki/Octopus_King%27s_Crown) says he always drops the crown.  This information could be incorrect, or this could be a bug (the game was released today).

[image]

Comment: It could be a bug.  I've gotten it for all the times I have beaten him.

Comment: I've gotten the drop about 50% of the time, maybe it depends if you already have one?

Comment: The Crown won't drop if you have one; I've killed him dozens of times (at least).  Note that an enchanted crown does not count.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, it doesn't seem to drop *every time* for some people. After the 5th time fighting the octopus king I received the crown. However It wasn't in the messages I had to look in my inventory afterward. So make sure to check your inventory each time you defeat him.

Answer (score 0):

The multiple drops are not a bug. Like the Leather Gloves the crown can be enchanted to get 1 of 2 properties by dropping a chocolate bar into the well.

You also need an unenchanted version of the crown to win a fight you can encounter when you use a certain potion.